# is it acceptable to store user password in localstore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have just implemented email/password auth. Now users need to register or sign in before they can see the rest of my site.

However I'm not clear about what to do when the client refreshes the page after they've already signed in. I want their "logged in" state to still be there, and to not require them to re-enter credentials.

It seems like an easy way to do this would be to store email/password in a client side cookie or localstorage. But I feel a little apprehensive about this. Is there a better way, or is this acceptable?

This app has no server other than firebase.com. I'm deploying the front end to github pages.

Comment: Well, *expect* that the user will screw with the saved data. Will that cause problems/security concerns?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think so. Since all that the credentials in localstorage areused for is to authenticate with firebase; my "user" object comes from their success response.

Comment: 95 % of php programmers do this.

Comment: Firebase automatically handles keeping the user signed in. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [firebase.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) function and only show the login page when they are not logged in?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```